# Clone Table Row Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a weird problem. I am creating a metabox for wordpress and came across an issue where a `<tr>` will not clone on .click. I am using a `while` php loop and can get div, p, a, etc tags to clone but not luck with the table. Here is a look at the code.

```
<?php while($mb->have_fields_and_multi('ingredients')) : ?>
     <?php $mb->the_group_open(); ?>
               <tr>
                 <td>Blah</td>
               </tr>
     <?php $mb->the_group_close(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?> 

<a href="#" class="docopy">add row</a>
```

Here is the javascript

```
$('[class*=docopy-]').click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            var p = $(this).parents('.postbox'); /*wp*/

            var the_name = $(this).attr('class').match(/docopy-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/i)[1];

            var the_group = $('.wpa_group-'+ the_name +'.tocopy', p).first();

            var the_clone = the_group.clone().removeClass('tocopy last');

            var the_props = ['name', 'id', 'for', 'class',];

            the_group.find('*').each(function(i, elem)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < the_props.length; j++)
                {
                    var the_prop = $(elem).attr(the_props[j]);

                    if (the_prop)
                    {
                        var the_match = the_prop.match(/\[(\d+)\]/i);

                        if (the_match)
                        {
                            the_prop = the_prop.replace(the_match[0],'['+ (+the_match[1]+1) +']');

                            $(elem).attr(the_props[j], the_prop);
                        }

                        the_match = null;

                        // todo: this may prove to be too broad of a search
                        the_match = the_prop.match(/n(\d+)/i);

                        if (the_match)
                        {
                            the_prop = the_prop.replace(the_match[0], 'n' + (+the_match[1]+1));

                            $(elem).attr(the_props[j], the_prop);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            if ($(this).hasClass('ontop'))
            {
                $('.wpa_group-'+ the_name, p).first().before(the_clone);
            }
            else
            {
                the_group.before(the_clone);
            }

            checkLoopLimit(the_name);

            $.wpalchemy.trigger('wpa_copy', [the_clone]);
        });

    });
```

I apologize for the amount of javascript and I couldn't replicate the problem just jsfiddle.

Comment: Class name is `docopy` and click event selector is `$('[class*=docopy-]')`.. Why that hyphen at the end..?  Also what does `not working` mean..? Any console errors..?

Comment: I must of removed it while trying to clean up the code a bit. It is present in my files.

Comment: What does the html look like?

Comment: This keeps gettins spit out. `<div class="wpa_group wpa_group-ingredients">                                </div>` Basically an empty div.